# Apache spark: how show method get top 20 across clusters so fast

Tags: apache-spark

I am intend to learn spark internals. So I have one question as how spark show method get
top 20 records across cluster so fast. For example, if I have 100k records per node, and I have 10 nodes, but when we say show(), how does it gets top 20 records?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the open source spark github repository and check the internal implementation of the same.

GitHub Repository URL : [Apache Spark GitHub Repository](https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark)

GitHub Repository Specific Class URL which has code for the show method implementation : [Dataset.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala)

You need to see the implementation for the function **showString** as it is the function which is called internally when you call **show** method.